# How / Where can I host my Java web application?

Tags: java, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Edit:  Just to be clear.  I want a place where I can do $>java myapp, where myapp uses plain old ServerSocket.  No jsp, no servlet, just very basic stuff -- may as well be a chargen server.

In case you want to skip to the crux of my inquiry just read the **bold** type.

I just finished my CS degree (at 39 years old :-)).  For my final project I designed and built a system that can provide local positioning / location awareness to mobile wifi devices (only have Android client thus far).  The server receives data from clients, processes it, and responds to the clients with a messages containing information about their respective locations.  I would like to continue the project (perhaps release as open source but that is a different discussion).  Thus far my server application has been running on the CS department's hardware where I could pretty much do whatever I wanted.  I'm getting kicked off that system in a few weeks so I have to find a new home for my server application.

**I need a host that will let me run my Java server (along w/ mySQL db) -- preferably on the cheap since I haven't yet got a job.  I have very little experience with the "real world" of web development / hosting.  I'm having trouble figuring out what kind of hosting service will let me run my application as is.  If that turns out to be a tall order then I need to know what my options are for changing thing so that I can get up and running with some hosting.**

As an aside, I'm also researching whether or not I should rewrite this in a different language.  Trying to figure out if there is a substantially better (for whatever reason) one for what I'm doing.  This might also potentially have a bearing on my hosting needs.  One possibility is to write the server in something more widely accepted by hosting services.

I have been searching for answers to my question and haven't found quite what I'm looking for.  Part of the problem might be that I don't know exactly what terminology to use.  If there is a good answer to this question elsewhere please feel free to point me towards it.

Thanks for help / advice.

Comment: Have you considered Google's [AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)? It supports Java and it's free. It doesn't have MySQL but it does have Google's Datastore, which is a more than adequate alternative.

Comment: Isn't your home computer good enough?

Comment: My home computer isn't going to cut it.  My ISP is neither cooperative nor reliable.

Comment: This question was closed and linked another as a duplicate.  The linked question has woefully inadequate answers.  That question appears to have been specifically designed to address the "I need web hosting.  What do I do?" question.  The answer is only a stub of answers and really provides no substantive help beyond a very general outline of what to think about.  It does not direct the reader to any resources where they might educate themselves or help themselves answer the questions that the "answer" asks the reader to address.

Comment: As per the meta discussion linked to in that answer, questions seeking web hosting advice are considered low quality for this site. As a result they all will be closed as a duplicate of that question. That question is relatively new so it isn't a great resource *yet*. It will take time and the effort of the users of this site to grow it into a valuable resource. If while trying to find a Java host you learn some good tips for others seeking similar hosting, please add it as an answer so future users of this site can benefit from your experience.

Comment: No worries.  I found a community willing to help out elsewhere.  It is looking like the answers to my question center on the facts that what I was looking for is not something widely on offer and that I need to look into restructuring my project.  That doesn't sound like the kind of answers the generalized linked question would get. Curious also that I didn't post to this site yet it was moved here and immediately deemed to be unworthy here.  I read the FAQ.  I sure thought I'd asked a 'practical, answerable question based on an actual problem that I face'.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [heroku.com](http://heroku.com), you will probably pay nothing for a small website (I have a commercial website running there and it is capable of serving millions of users per month for free). You also have a PostgreSQL database available for free to get started with, which is very similar to MySQL.

I would really recommend this, the skills you will learn will really set you up well for the future.